# What do Asharites say "free will" is?

Tags: free-will, aqidah

Some time ago I posted a question about free will, qadr, and justice [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/37835/17702). It was closed as being too broad, so I'm posting separate questions regarding those topics. For context and details of what I'm looking for, refer to that question.

My question here is: **what do the Asharites say "free will" consists of, and in what sense is it "free"?**

To clarify the second part, questions like "is it free from Allah's intervention" or "is it free from other creations like inclinations, impulses, sense experience" are what I have in mind there. In particular, a person's motivations are part of creation, so I'm hoping to see the relation between the choices a person makes and his motivations addressed in the answers.

Comment: They say that although we have free will, we can't create anything in nature ( material world/physical world) which also refers to life as only Allah can.

Answer (score -3):

In short, it is a complicated concept mentioned in Qura'an besides the concept of **pre-destiny**. Many of the religious and secular scholars have spun their heads explaining the concept of **"Free-will"** but have miserably failed. The best exhortation, I have come across, in this respect, is that of Imam Ghazali. Which is also inconclusive and ends at the threshold of **pre-destiny**.

Muslim have to believe in **Free-will** for it is mentioned in Qura'an (most likely under the cloak of **Bila-Kaif**) for its exact nature and working alongside **pre-destiny** is known only to Allah (SWT).

Comment: brother, it's HEAVILY discouraged to link to your blog at the end of each answer. If you like to do such, then do it on your profile page. Links are used for references or if your answer is the gist and the site contains 10X more of the answer

Comment: Hm, this answer doesn't provide information that would help me out with my question; could you point me to where al-Ghazali discussed free will?

Comment: I don't see how this answers his question at all.

Comment: One does not have to be sect-specific for a logical and rational answer. What is Asharite's point of view you already know it else won't be asking a question about it. Comprehend the answer, therefore, in a broader perspective, which might be helpful to a greater number of people rather than just you.

Comment: I'm asking sect-specific because a more general version of the question, as can be seen in the only link in this question, was closed for being too broad. I don't know what the Asharites say, and that's why I'm asking.